# Как поставить default value в Combobox tkinter Python?

Tags: python, tkinter

Хочу, чтобы было изначально выбрано значение "Неделя", а получается, что там пустое поле

```
    choiceVar = StringVar()
    choices = ("Месяц", "Неделя")
    choiceVar.set(choices[1])
    self.cb = ttk.Combobox(self.root, textvariable=choiceVar, values=choices, width=10, state='readonly', exportselection=0)
    self.cb.place(x=740, y=30)
```

[image: Как получилось]
[image: Как хочу]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
self.cb = ttk.Combobox(self.root, values=("Месяц", "Неделя"))
self.cb.current(1)
```